# iOS App Crash when removing all objects from nsmutable array?

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am unable to understand what mistake is done by me, when I am trying to remove all objects from mutable array.My project is ARC enable
my code snippet

```
 self.arrMonthHas =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 if([self.arrMonthHas count ])
       [self.arrMonthHas removeAllObjects];
```

please help me with current solution.

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Comment: what you stored in your array?

Comment: no need for the if. loose it

Comment: that code you show assigns a new array and then clears it right away?

Comment: without adding object why u remove all object ?

Comment: Please Post your error here to understand it clearly.

Comment: This is not the actual code, another time waster.

Comment: No need of if([self.arrMonthHas count ])
       [self.arrMonthHas removeAllObjects];.... It will be always blank b'cas its just allocated above.

Comment: we wouldn't know that -- it could be filled in the setter. hence my question

Comment: Where are the crash logs?

Answer (score 1):

After removing all objects from `self.arrMonthHas`, please ensure that `self.arrMonthHas` is not encountered anywhere else. Because though all the objects are removed but still memory is allocated for the same. So if you try to access any element of your array, it will crash.

**P.S. Please post your error.**

Comment: dont get it... and why shouldn't it be encountered anymore? What do you mean?

Comment: @Daij-Djan : Because though all the objects are removed but still memory is allocated for the same. So if you try to access any element of your array, it will crash.

Comment: yes, they are retained but no longer in the array -- if you access the former array items though, nothing is gone crash

Comment: the array have of course a count of 0 as the items aren't in the array

Comment: @Daij-Djan: What do you mean by former array ?

Comment: well, everything that still holds onto the array (e.g. another view controller) works with the old value that the retained when they read the property. now he is updating the property but that doesn't dealloc the old array that others have retained....

Comment: using the `setter` method ensure the previous memory if any is release & new allocated. So there is no point of former or latter.

Comment: Release != Dealloc -- but hey whatever

Answer (score 0):

You need to add few objects to the array before removing them, what you have done here is intialized a new instance of mutable array and flushed it's contents which are not present in the array at the first place, you could do something like

```
self.arrMontHas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstObject,secondObject,thirdObject,nil];
```

and then based upon your business logic you may remove all the objects of the array

```
if(someBusinessCondition == YES)
{
  [self.arrMonthHas removeAllObjects];
}
```

Hope this helps